# jQuery and capturing when a google search button clicked

Tags: jquery, search

I have a google search set up:
http://www.merrittnet.org/search/gardening

the button I am tryong tom  capture the click event for is:

```
<button class="gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2"><svg width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><title>search</title><path d="m4.8495 7.8226c0.82666 0 1.5262-0.29146 2.0985-0.87438 0.57232-0.58292 0.86378-1.2877 0.87438-2.1144 0.010599-0.82666-0.28086-1.5262-0.87438-2.0985-0.59352-0.57232-1.293-0.86378-2.0985-0.87438-0.8055-0.010599-1.5103 0.28086-2.1144 0.87438-0.60414 0.59352-0.8956 1.293-0.87438 2.0985 0.021197 0.8055 0.31266 1.5103 0.87438 2.1144 0.56172 0.60414 1.2665 0.8956 2.1144 0.87438zm4.4695 0.2115 3.681 3.6819-1.259 1.284-3.6817-3.7 0.0019784-0.69479-0.090043-0.098846c-0.87973 0.76087-1.92 1.1413-3.1207 1.1413-1.3553 0-2.5025-0.46363-3.4417-1.3909s-1.4088-2.0686-1.4088-3.4239c0-1.3553 0.4696-2.4966 1.4088-3.4239 0.9392-0.92727 2.0864-1.3969 3.4417-1.4088 1.3553-0.011889 2.4906 0.45771 3.406 1.4088 0.9154 0.95107 1.379 2.0924 1.3909 3.4239 0 1.2126-0.38043 2.2588-1.1413 3.1385l0.098834 0.090049z"></path></svg></button>
```

I am trying to use the jQuery below , I get no error so class of .gsc-search-button
doesn't seem to be the correct object.Any ideas?

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(".gsc-search-button").on('click', function(event){
    alert(".gsc-search-button");
    });
 </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: That code is in the head before any elements exist. In addition there is an ancient version of jQuery (1.4) being loaded at the bottom of the page. It will make your `on()` throw error inside `document.ready` since on() didn't exist back then

Comment: Hey Charlie I moved the script to the bottom and removed the extra j!uery definition still doesnt seem to fire on click

Comment: Use that inside document ready `$(()=> {  // your code });`

Comment: Hi Kiran that works on page refresh but doesnt fire when I clike that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these if it works

```
$(()=> {  
   $(".gsc-search-button").on('click', function(event){
    alert(".gsc-search-button");
    });
});
```

If the above not work try this

```
$(()=> {  
   $(document).on('click', ".gsc-search-button" , function(event){
        alert(".gsc-search-button");
    });
});
```

Please see working version with your code.

```html
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=0e7979155b7270dbd"></script>

<meta content="Mon, 04 Feb 2019 10:40:07 -0440" name="date" />

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />

<!--link href="../css/default.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /-->


<link href="search-mq.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
  <!-- @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
  -->
</style>

<style>
  div.gsc-adBlock {
    display: none;
  }
</style>


<!--script type="text/javascript">
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11973977-13']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'usask.ca']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script-->


<div id="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 id="uofs">
      <a href="/"><img alt="Gardenline" src="../images/usask.png" height=40 width=40 /></a> <span id="site-name">Search</span></h1>
    <!-- search form -->
    <div id="search-options">


      <div>
        <div class="gcse-searchbox"></div>
        <div class="gcse-searchresults" linkTarget="_blank"></div>
      </div>


      <span id="clear-form" onclick="clearSearch();" style="display:none;"></span>
    </div>

    <noscript>
<p>
This page requires javascript.  Please enable javascript, or use our
<a href="http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=0e7979155b7270dbd">Google Gardenline search</a>
instead.
</p>
</noscript>
  </div>
</div>
<ul id="m-nav" style="display:none;">
  <li><a class="active" href="#web" onclick="showResultsTab(this,'web'); return false;"><span class="icon web" ></span>Web</a></li>
  <li><a href="#map" onclick="showResultsTab(this,'map'); return false;"><span class="icon map" ></span>Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="#people" onclick="showResultsTab(this,'people'); return false;"><span class="icon people" ></span>People</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content-and-context" style="display:none;">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="context">
      <div id="people">
        <ul id="m-nav-people" style="display:none;">
          <li class="active" onclick="showPeopleTab(this,'phone');"><span class="icon phone"></span>Phone directory</li>
          <li onclick="showPeopleTab(this,'email');"><span class="icon email"></span>Email directory</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="people_results"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="hide" id="map">
        <h2>Map</h2>
        <div id="map_canvas">
          <div id="map_result"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="map_list"></div>
      </div>


      <div id="web">
        <h2>Web</h2>
        <input id="hidden-input" style="display:none" />
        <div id="results" style="width: 90%;">
          <script>
            (function() {
              var cx = '0e7979155b7270dbd';
              var gcse = document.createElement('script');
              gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
              gcse.async = true;
              gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
              var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
              s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
            })();
          </script>
          <div style='display:none;'>
            <gcse:searchbox enableHistory='true'></gcse:searchbox>
          </div>
          <gcse:searchresults webSearchQueryAddition=' -filetype:pdf -filetype:doc -filetype:gz -filetype:xml -filetype:ps -filetype:Z' linkTarget='_self'></gcse:searchresults>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="search-footer" style="display:none;">


</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(() => {
    $(document).on('click', ".gsc-search-button", function(event)     {
      alert(".gsc-search-button");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can also try changing `$(document)` to nearest ancestor of the button eg: `$('body')`  or `$('#search-options')`